# Can't connect to openvpn server in docker

Tags: docker, server, openvpn, openvpn-connect

So I am trying to run a OpenVPN server in a docker container on my VirtualBox Xubuntu VM and connect to the server from the hosting Windows 10. I ran the server, but I can't seem to connect. I disabled both firewalls (on the host machine/the client) and on the Xubuntu hosting the docker server (I ran sudo ufw disable and then sudo ufw status and it said "Status: inactive").

On Windows I'm using the OpenVPN GUI and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZwKM.png) is its console output.

Here is my client .ovpn configuration file (I added the two lines:

```
cipher AES-256-CBC 
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC
```

because before this I had another error "--cipher is not set. Previous OpenVPN version defaulted to BF-CBC as fallback when cipher negotiation failed in this case. If you need this fallback please add '--data-ciphers-fallback BF-CBC' to your configuration and/or add BF-CBC to --data-ciphers." and that seems to have fixed that issue):

```
client
nobind
dev tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC

remote 10.0.2.15 1194 udp

<key>
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----

-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>

redirect-gateway def1
```

Comment: Disabled all firewalls? Without firewall docker cannot route traffic to containers....

Comment: @pierpy so should I only enable the VM's firewalls?

Comment: yes, maybe it's the problem. After setting correct cypher lines, Ubuntu FW was disabled?

Comment: I disabled it manually. I tried enabling it now, but still the same error.

Comment: No luck... Don't know what to try then. Maybe a Virtualbox issue